# export to excel 404 issue on server in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working MVC4 project with devexpress with custom export to excel code. Code is working well on my local. I am able to download xls file without any issue but when i deployed on server i am getting 404 error when i click on export to excel.

I have checked permission ,everyrole has full control.

Here is my code for export to excel :

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            try
            {   

                GridView gridView = new GridView();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "ShopFloorReport" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH:mm") + ".xls"));
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

                gridView.AllowPaging = false;
                gridView.DataSource = ReportExecutor.GetShopReportExportData(startDate, endDate);
                gridView.DataBind();

                //This will change the header background color
                gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); //

                //This will apply style to gridview header cells
                for (int index = 0; index < gridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; index++)
                {
                    gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[index].Style.Add("background-color", "#778899"); //Light Slate Gray
                    gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[index].Style.Add("foreground-color", "#ffffff"); // White
                }

                int index2 = 1;
                //This will apply style to alternate rows
                foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gridView.Rows)
                {
                    gridViewRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                    if (index2 <= gridView.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        if (index2 % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            for (int index3 = 0; index3 < gridViewRow.Cells.Count; index3++)
                            {
                                gridViewRow.Cells[index3].Style.Add("background-color", "#e6e6fa");// Lavender
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    index2++;
                }

                gridView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

                Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
                Response.End();

            }
            catch 
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not an answer that you expects, but it may help. Here is similar code that I use for exporting data to excel. It works fine. You may try this. If you get an error, that will mean that you are having a problem with method, which gets datasource.

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel ()
{
GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = GetYourDataSource() // Method you use to get data for export         
            gv.DataBind();            
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

return Json("Success");
}
```